# If I downgrade pdf version from 1.7 to 1.4 using itext7 will it cause any distortion

Tags: java, itext7

While downgrading pdf version from 1.7 to 1.4 will itext7 cause any distortion.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what "distortion" means.

If you mean visual incompatibility, then in **practice** there shouldn't be a difference. I say "shouldn't" because if you read the specification, there should be some features that shouldn't be supported anymore. But from experience I notice that a lot of PDF viewers are very lenient when it comes to a PDF that contains features that aren't in its declared version.

So, you should be fine, but I have to stress that you shouldn't assume everybody uses Adobe Reader/Foxit and expect the PDF file to work for everyone as intended.